# Firebase how to create users?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am not familiar with the new Firebase. How do I create new users? The code below I Signup and `auth` new user. If I need to create this new user under "Customers" in `Firebase Database`, what code do I need to add? Thanks!

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, err) in

   if err != nil {

         self.showAlert("Can't Register", msg: "Please enter email and password")

      } else {   

          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(user?.uid, forKey: "uid")

           FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        })

         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecondVC", sender: self)
     }

  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, err) in

 if err != nil {

     self.showAlert("Can't Register", msg: "Please enter email and password")

  } else {   

      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(user?.uid, forKey: "uid")

     FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Customers").setValue([user!.uid : "true"])

     //Or if you want to save the users Details too:- 
     /*

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Customers").setValue([user!.uid : ["email" : email,"password" : password]])

     */
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecondVC", sender: self)
    }
})
```

Also might i suggest reading this :  [Firebase iOS - Save Data](http:////firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, but I'd recommend doing it this way:

```
var values = [Any : Any] // This is a dictionary where you can store user details
values["userUID"] = // user's uid
values["usersName"] = // user's name
// etc.

let customerRef = databaseReference.child("Customers") // You could also add a child with the user's UID in order to identify each user

customerRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

    if error != nil {

        // display error.code and error.localizedDescription to user if needed

    } else if ref != [] {

        // Success!
        // If needed, save the user to NSUserDefaults and perfrom a segue to another ViewController

    } else {

        // There was an error, but not sure what happened. Let the user know how they can fix the problem (maybe add the details to the database later)

    }
})
```